# Issue adding site-packages directory to PYTHONPATH in Spyder

Tags: python, path, spyder

I am using Spyder and trying to add `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`  to the PYTHONPATH Manager. However, I receive an error informing me "This directory cannot be added to PATH. If you want to set a different Python interpreter, please go to Preferences > Main Interpreter".

However, I have already changed my interpreter to point to `/usr/bin/python3`

At the moment, I am using the rather annoying work around of putting the following at the top of all my code.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages")
```

Typing the following gives me the below. Is there a way which I can even ensure after running `pip3 install XXX` in the terminal, that the packages are downloaded somewhere such as the below?

```
for p in sys.path: print(p)

/Users/user
/usr/local/lib/python3.7
/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip
/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7
/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload

/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aeosa
/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions
/Users/user/.ipython
```

Alternatively, and preferably, advice on how to add the above site-packages directory to my PATH? I feel I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) We forbid adding `site-packages` directories through our PYTHONPATH manager because it allows people to mix two different Python versions (which is what you're trying to do by adding your system `site-packages` to your Anaconda's Python).

And we do that because it usually generates odd errors and segfaults for binary packages such as Numpy, Pandas and Matplotlib, given that binary packages for one Python version are incompatible with packages for another one.

Finally, even though you found a workaround for that (by using `sys.path`), we strongly suggest you to stop doing that because it'll give you nothing by headaches in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I appreciate it. So the solution here is to ensure pip installs packages to another location which Spyder can see?

Comment: If I'm using a virtualenv and point the interpreter to it, how do I ensure spyder looks at the packages installed there first? In my case, spyder looks at `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`before the virtualenv, and so it uses system packages when I want to use the virtualenv.

Comment: for me (using standalone Spyder on macOS), changing the interpreter doesn't solve this issue. Regardless of the interpreter I use, I cannot import my module or add `site-packages` to the path. What I did was to install Spyder through conda using `conda install Spyder`. Launching via terminal using `Spyder` now works

Comment: @gaut Using the Python interpreter that was used to install the module will automatically use the correct site-packages directories as explained in my new answer. That is why you can't add it manually. I also explained how to install your module in the environment of the Python interpreter you chose. That way you can keep using a release version of Spyder while also being able to import your module whether it is installed globally in your example or elsewhere (Instead of installing the conda version of Spyder in the environment of your module and launching Spyder via the terminal).

Answer (score -1):

Doing what you are asking isn't the recommended path forward but you can solve the underlying problem in either of the following ways (A or B).

To "ensure pip installs packages to another location which Spyder can see" as the asker guessed in a comment on the accepted answer which got no answer (Method B below) is usually not a good idea. Keeping a clean environment for Spyder will ensure that you can determine requirements (including package version) for each of your projects reliably. Therefore, do the reverse of what you guessed: Ensure Spyder uses the Python interpreter in the environment where pip installed your project's required packages.

A. Change the Python interpreter

1. Go to Tools, Preferences, and set Python interpreter to the python executable that was used to install the package (If using a virtual environment, it would be your_other_env/bin/python).
2. Close and reopen Spyder (Spyder says to restart the IPython console, but it may not work in this case and show the error where Spyder cannot restart a kernel it didn't start).
3. Open Spyder again and run any py file. You will get an error that says to install the `spyder-kernels` package (for some reason pip 22.0.4 will only install `spyder_kernels`: This issue is at "[spyder-kernels should be spyder_kernels](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/18051)" :edit: but the issue is invalid, so upgrade pip first such as via `pip install --upgrade pip` in your virtual environment). *Take note of the version in the error, since that is the version you need.*
4. If you are using conda or are on Windows the instructions will differ, so see [Common Illnesses](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/troubleshooting/common-illnesses.html) in the Spyder documentation instead of continuing this step.

```
source your_other_env/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
pip install spyder-kernels=...
deactivate
```

but change `...` to the version shown in your Spyder error from step 3. If you installed Spyder with conda as recommended, use the commands from the URL above instead.

I don't recommend Method B, as I've explained. However, it may be useful if you are manually installing Spyder plugins or test suites that apply to all projects but aren't in the requirements.txt or setup.py requirements for your project(s) (and therefore don't affect determining requirements for your users).

B. To "ensure pip installs packages to another location which Spyder can see" you would run "spyder_env/bin/python -m pip install ..."  to install the package, where spyder_env is the virtualenv where Spyder is installed (but if Spyder is installed in the system using an installer or linux distro package, you may need to use your system's python such as via `python3 -m pip install --user ...` where ... is the package name. Always use --user instead of sudo or root to avoid mismatched files caused by mashing together the distro-packaged modules and your manually installed modules).

Comment: The accepted answer can be summarized as "You can't" but I offered a different thing to do to solve the underlying problem, and my answer is in line with the Spyder documentation. Therefore I'm not sure why this is down-voted, so some sort of comment instead would be helpful.